# How to display and identify all days (e.g monday, tuesday) per month individually?

Tags: sql, oracle, dayofweek

Please help me. I stuck for many hours. I want to display all days (e.g monday, tuesday) individually every month and display also the respective date of each days.

How can I do that? I really need help, please. Thank you

Desired output:

```
Data,Date,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday
Data,04/01/2014,10,12,5,6,1,0,15
Data,04/07/2014,14,1,5,6,1,2,18
Data,04/14/2014,11,12,5,6,1,0,17
```

Here's the SQL Script:

```
select 'Data'
||','||to_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
||','||nvl(m.mtotal, 0)
||','||nvl(tu.tutotal, 0)
||','||nvl(w.wtotal, 0)
||','||nvl(th.thtotal, 0)
||','||nvl(f.ftotal, 0)
||','||nvl(s.stotal, 0)
||','||nvl(su.sutotal, 0)
from table0.dc_date d
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time) as monday
              ,count(t.create_time) as mtotal
        from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time)
) m on d.dtime_day = m.monday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as tuesday
              ,count(t.create_time) as tutotal
        from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'

        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) tu on d.dtime_day = tu.tuesday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as wednesday
              ,count(t.create_time) as wtotal
         from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) w on d.dtime_day = w.wednesday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as thursday
              ,count(t.create_time) as thtotal
         from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) th on d.dtime_day = th.thursday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as friday
              ,count(t.create_time) as ftotal
        from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) f on d.dtime_day = f.friday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as saturday
              ,count(t.create_time) as stotal
        from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) s on d.dtime_day = s.saturday
left join (
        select trunc(t.create_time, 'DD') as sunday
              ,count(t.create_time) as sutotal
        from table.table1 t
        left join table.table2 q
        on q.id = t.queue_id
        where t.create_time between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and sysdate -1
        and q.name not like 'item0%'
        or q.name not like 'item%'
        group by trunc(t.create_time, 'DD')
) su on d.dtime_DAY = su.sunday
where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate,'DD')-12*7 and trunc(sysdate) -1
and trunc(d.dtime_day, 'DD')= d.dtime_day
order by d.dtime_day
```

[image]

I want to show the date also in every day

Comment: You might want to post some starting data.  How is this failing you?  Note that Oracle has `PIVOT`, which means you don't have to do it like this.  Assuming `create_time` is a timestamp, [you want to avoid](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the left-join sub-queries seem to be doing the same thing, and you aren't actually restricting anything on the day of the week. You only need to join once, and then you need to pivot the results of that join. You could use a real pivot if you're on 11g:

```
select 'Data'
  ||','|| to_char(week_start, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  ||','|| mon_cnt
  ||','|| tue_cnt
  ||','|| wed_cnt
  ||','|| thu_cnt
  ||','|| fri_cnt
  ||','|| sat_cnt
  ||','|| sun_cnt
from (
  select 'Data',
    next_day(d.dtime_day - 7, 'Monday') as week_start,
    to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') as day_of_week,
    t.create_time
  from dc_date d
  left join table1 t
  on t.create_time >= d.dtime_day
  and t.create_time < d.dtime_day + 1
  left join table2 q
  on q.id = t.queue_id
  and (q.name not like 'item0%' or q.name not like 'item%')
  where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate) - (12*7) and trunc(sysdate) -1
)
pivot (count(create_time) as cnt for (day_of_week)
  in ('Mon' as mon, 'Tue' as tue, 'Wed' as wed, 'Thu' as thu,
    'Fri' as fri, 'Sat' as sat, 'Sun' as sun))
order by week_start;
```

If you aren't on 11g you can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
select 'Data'
  ||','|| to_char(next_day(d.dtime_day - 7, 'Monday'), 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Mon'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Tue'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Web'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Thu'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Fri'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Sat'
    then t.create_time end)
  ||','|| count(case when to_char(d.dtime_day, 'Dy') = 'Sun'
    then t.create_time end)
from dc_date d
left join table1 t
on t.create_time >= d.dtime_day
and t.create_time < d.dtime_day + 1
left join table2 q
on q.id = t.queue_id
and (q.name not like 'item0%' or q.name not like 'item%')
where d.dtime_day between trunc(sysdate) - (12*7) and trunc(sysdate) -1
group by next_day(d.dtime_day - 7, 'Monday')
order by next_day(d.dtime_day - 7, 'Monday');
```

The day names are NLS-sensitive, so the `to_char` calls should really have the optional third parameter to enforce the language; but I've used `next_day` to do the grouping and that relies on the session settings, so your session has to be in English anyway - or at least, all the values used for day names have to be consistent with your session language. That will be an issue if this can be run by anyone, but if this is a script to generate a report then you can set the language in the script as a workaround.

You haven't supplied table structures or data so I've made some up. With this:

```
create table dc_date (dtime_day date);
insert into dc_date
select date '2014-03-28' + level
from dual
connect by level < 30;

create table table1 (create_time date, queue_id number);
insert into table1 values (sysdate - 1, 1);
insert into table1 values (sysdate - 0.75, 1);
insert into table1 values (sysdate - 5, 1);
insert into table1 values (sysdate - 10, 1);
insert into table1 values (sysdate - 15, 1);

create table table2 (id number, name varchar2(10));
insert into table2 values (1, 'anything');
```

... both queries get:

```
Data,03/24/2014,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Data,03/31/2014,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Data,04/07/2014,0,1,0,0,0,0,1
Data,04/14/2014,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
Data,04/21/2014,0,2,0,0,0,0,0
```

I created two records for yesterday, so `2` appears in the 'Tuesday' column, for the week that starts (on Monday) on April 21st. Which I think is what you want.

Comment: Pole it is possible to display the date also with respective day of it?

Comment: @Yang - sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe add the output you want now to the question?

Comment: Pole i want also display the respective date of day per week e.g. Monday 04/01/2014,Tuesday 04/02/2014

Comment: @Yang - but where? Your output has data for 12 weeks, so the day/datefow which week, and  how does this relate to the output of the counts? It would be easier to show an example of what you want.

Comment: Pole lets say we have 1 week, in 1 week we have 7 days and in each day has a respective date, right? Like in your script, the output of that is showing the date per week and each week shows the number of data with day name right? Now, I want is to show both days and date per week

Comment: See the photo that i uploaded in my question. You see the tooltip (comment box) in the graph? The day is tuesday but the display date is 03/24/2014 instead of 03/25/2014, right? Because 24 is monday

Comment: How are you converting the grid output from the query into the graph? Adding the dates, and maybe even doing the counting, sounds like something the graphing tool should be handling.

Comment: i use xslt to produce data and graph. So its not possible to display date also?

Comment: @Yang - I have no idea how you're converting the CSV form the query into XML for XSLT to work on. I imagine it's possible from the XML side - but why not get the query output in the format you need? Anyway, this is now so far from your original query that I think you should ask a new question, showing how you're transforming the query output all the way through to the chart, and what you need to change - whether that's how to get extra fields in the CSV, or XML output. I can't tell what you want at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Pole, i already know that how to transform. All I need is how to query the day with date itself in sql

Comment: @Yang - but you haven't shown what you want the CSV to look like now. You asked for the count per day of the week, within each week. I don't know where you want the dates to appear in the CSV you showed originally. I can't change the query to show the format you want if I don't know what that format is.

Comment: Pole, i want to combine the dates with the days. I mean in one column the dates and days are merged